# Iterate through R hash table (dictionary) to extract keys and values for variable assignment and function arguments

Tags: r

I have the following dictionary in R:

```
library(hash)

symbol_mapping <- hash('a'='red', 'b'='white', 'c'='blue')
symbol_mapping

<hash> containing 3 key-value pair(s).
  a : red
  b : white
  c : blue
```

I would like to populate variable names function arguments by reading the key-value pairs of the `symbol_mapping` hash table, as follows:

```
a <- print('red')
b <- print('white')
c <- print('blue')
```

What's the best way to avoid hard-coding the variable names and function arguments?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `as.list(values(symbol_mapping))`?

Comment: No, I would like to effectively **populate** the variable names using the dictionary keys and populate the function arguments using the dictionary values.

Comment: The best practice advice is not to do this (it clutters your global environment and will silently overwrite existing variables should they already exist).  It's **strongly** recommended to work from a list, as per my first comment.